# The AppBarLayout and ToolBar is overlapping with ScrollView and it's child layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-xml, android-appbarlayout

I trying to add ToolBar to this layout, but I seeing the `titleTextView` is hidding behind the toolbar becasue the ScrollView is first child in layout, I tried to make ScrollView `layout_height="wrap_content"` but also not working

here's the full layout xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detailsActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icons8_share_480"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="start|bottom"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="50dp"
                android:text="some text"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="20sp"

                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this image with AppBarLayout

[detailsActivity AppBar issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYhOH.jpg)

this without AppBarLayout

[detailsActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWMCN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the root layout to LinearLayout and make `AppBarLayout` the child of it, and put all other layouts insde `CoordinatorLayout`

here's the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detailsActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DetailsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icons8_share_480"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="start|bottom"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="50dp"
                android:text="some text"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="20dp"

                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```